# Roll a wheel along a curving path accurately

Tags: animation, drivers, path

This seems like it should be so straightforward (for someone a bit cleverer than me), but I want to be able to roll a wheel accurately along a **curving** path, with the roll being driven by the follow path offset factor, incorporating acceleration and deceleration of this f-curve. Can anyone explain a solid solution for this, either with drivers, which seems the most straightforward, or a geometry nodes solution? I know the length of my curve (190m) and the circumference of my wheel (2.2m). Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to point you at a comprehensive YT [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMIySP_2Qjg). It's quite an old one and I think uses Blender 2.79 but covers everything you're likely to need and the method is the same in recent versions.

Comment: Thank you so much John. This is just what I was after but couldn't find it for looking. Are you Alien Soup? These are some of the best tutorials I've found for blender, brilliantly clear, non-nonsese, with clever and elegant solutions, and practical Blender skills that can be used in a number of different ways. I can't believe this was right under my nose after all. I'll go through it and update this thread after. Brilliant!

Comment: No. I'm not 'Alien Soup'! I keep a folder of links to tutorials and add one if I find one that interests me.

Comment: He remains a mystery! Thanks anyway John, really appreciate you pointing me towards this.